# Google AdminReports API

Tags: api, google-apps-script

I've managed to write various action scripts with Classroom, DriveApp and one or two others.  However, I'm having a problem with AdminReports.  I think that it may be because it's an 'Advanced Service' but I'm unclear on the steps required to make this API available.  Can anyone recommend a step-by-step guide for this please.

Answer (score 1):

[**Enable Advanced Google Services:**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)

To use an advanced Google service, follow these instructions:

**New Editor:**

[image]

**Legacy Editor:**

[image]

---

**Example using the new editor:**

- Select `Admin SDK API`
- Select `reports_v1` as API Version
- **(Optional)** Replace `AdminDirectory` with `AdminReports`

[image]

---

Additional Reference: [Sample Admin Reports API usage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports#sample_code)